# How to fix ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to monitor my docker container ram use. Now I found a script online that generates a txt file with the stats like so:

```
LOG_FILE="/volume1/docker/docker-logs.txt"

while true;
do
    sleep 10m
    docker stats --format "{{.Name}}, {{.MemUsage}}" --no-stream >> $LOG_FILE
    #echo "-" >> $LOG_FILE
done
```

Have it running at boot with my Synology NAS. Works fine I get this file:

```
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 160.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 255.4MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 96.87MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 112.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 212.2MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 68.34MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 258.3MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 101.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 114.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 212.4MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 71.06MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 262.7MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 102.2MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 124.1MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 217.7MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 81.38MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 262.7MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 102.5MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 125.1MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 217.6MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 76.55MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 269.2MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 103.3MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 123.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 219MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
Python3, 46.42MiB / 150MiB
hassio, 77.52MiB / 3.855GiB
Jacket, 268.4MiB / 3.855GiB
Radarrnodebug, 106.2MiB / 3.855GiB
Sonarrnodebug, 117.8MiB / 3.855GiB
Ombii, 213.1MiB / 3.855GiB
watchtower, 11.48MiB / 50MiB
-
```

Now to make it as a nice PNG I have the following:

```
from pip._internal import main
main(["install", "matplotlib", "numpy","pandas"])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

log_path = "/stats/docker-logs.txt"

with open(log_path) as f:
    raw_data = f.readlines()
nrows = 8
n = len(raw_data) // nrows
data = []
for i in range(n):
    start = i * nrows
    end = start + nrows - 1
    d = raw_data[start:end]
    datum = {}
    datum['i'] = i
    for line in d:
        name, stats = line.strip().split(',')
        stats = float(stats.split('/')[0].strip()[:-3])
        datum[name] = stats
    data.append(datum)

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['time (hour)'] = data['i'] * 10 / 60
ax = data.drop(columns='i').set_index('time (hour)').plot()
ax.set_ylabel('RAM Usage (MiB)')
ax.figure.savefig('/stats/plot.png')
```

Which worked fine in the beginnen but out of the blue it stopped working and I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/stats/genstat.py", line 22, in <module>
    name, stats = line.strip().split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Did some debugging and found out that

```
var i
```

became 0 so nothing worked anymore (since it has to skip the "-" char) what happened and how do i fixed it? I tried a lot already by removing the "-" char, chaning the nrows but nothing really matters (to meeeee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more pythonic:

```
if ',' not in line:
    continue
name, stats = line.strip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
name, stats = line.strip().split(',')
```

is failing because you have a line in your input file that has no comma in it. And it is very likely a blank line at the end. Do

```
columns = line.strip().split(',')
if len(columns) == 2:
    name, stats = columns
else:
    print("Expected name and stats, got", columns)
```

Comment: The print error was a placeholder to show that something was wrong with the input. I could not guess how you wanted to respond to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
if line.count(',') != 1:
    continue
name, stats = line.strip().split(',')
```

Comment: if some line contain more than one comma it will skip it

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan unpack fails when there's not enough values **or too many**

Comment: yeah , can capture everything else in state though by using *state